# elasticsearch bulkload performance issue

Tags: elasticsearch, bulk-load

We want to increase the speed of bulk-load.

Now we used JAVA to bulk load documents to Elasticsearch. We planned to import 10m documents each document size is almost 8M. Now we only can import 400K documents each day/ 5 documents every second.
Our ES infrastructure is 3 master node with 4G ES_JAVA_OPTS(heap size) 2 data nodes and 2 client nodes with 2G memory. When I want to increase the speed of bulk-load, we will get over the heap size issue. we set up the es cluster on Kubernetes.
The I/O is below.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/data/tmp/test1.img bs=1G count=10 oflag=dsync
10737418240 bytes (11 GB) copied, 50.7528 s, 212 MB/s

dd if=/dev/zero of=/data/tmp/test2.img bs=512 count=100000 oflag=dsync
51200000 bytes (51 MB) copied, 336.107 s, 152 kB/s
```

Any advice for the improvement?

```
    for (int x =0; x<200000;x++) {
        BulkRequest bulkRequest = new BulkRequest();
        for (int k = 0; k < 50; k++) {
            Order order = generateOrder();
            IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("orderpot", "orderpot");
            Object esDataMap = objectToMap(order);
            String source = JSONObject.valueToString(esDataMap);
            indexRequest.source(source, XContentType.JSON);
            bulkRequest.add(indexRequest);
        }
        rhlclient.bulk(bulkRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

over heap size

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need more memory for data node.10m documents with 8M each will cost a lot of memory.And you can reduce the memory of master node and add on data nodes, master node need less memory than data nodes, and if there is no more nodes, you can combine the client nodes with data nodes, more data nodes with share the pressure.
Some other advise:
1. disable refresh by setting index.refresh_interval to -1 and set index.number_of_replicas to 0, when indexing.
2. set a mapping for your index, do not use default mapping, for example:some fields can be integer no need to use long, some fields can be text but keyword will never be used, and some fields will only be used as text.

[tune-for-indexing-speed given by official][1]https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html